# How to fetch the array of objects with array object and array list based on conditions using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dictionary, object

I have array of objects, and arrays

how to compare based on conditions using javascript

1. fetch the array of objects having same `value` property
2. then, based on value list If check `cid` is same, return both array of objects
3. or then, based on value list Else check `cid` is different but includes of `IN` or `FI` return empty

   or return that array object

```
var listcode =["IN","FI"];
var listarr1 =[
  {id:1, name: "dino", cid: "IN", value: "A1234"},
  {id:2, name: "hem", cid: "IN", value: "B3456"},
  {id:3, name: "zen", cid: "SP", value: "B3456"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", cid: "FI", value: "C5678"},
]

var listarr2 =[
  {id:1, name: "dino", cid: "IN", value: "A1234"},
  {id:2, name: "hem", cid: "IN", value: "B3456"},
  {id:3, name: "zen", cid: "SG", value: "C5678"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", cid: "SP", value: "C5678"},
]

Expected Output 
//same value , and has "IN" 
//listarr1
[]

//listarr2
//same value no include of `FI or IN` so return
[
  {id:3, name: "zen", cid: "SG", value: "C5678"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", cid: "SP", value: "C5678"}
] 

I tried

const checkIdMembers = list => {
    const idlist = ['IN', 'FI'];
    const resultarray = list
      .map((obj, i) => list.find((element, index) => {
        if (i !== index && element.value === obj.value && 
           (element.cid === obj.cid || idlist.includes(element.cid)) {
          return obj;
        }
      }))
      .filter(x => x);
    return resultarray;
  };
  
  
  const result = checkIdMembers(listarr1);
```

Comment: can you show example of your output ?

Answer (score 1):

It think it's easier if you invert the order of the operations

```js
const listcode =["IN","FI"];
const listarr1 =[
  {id:1, name: "dino", cid: "IN", value: "A1234"},
  {id:2, name: "hem", cid: "IN", value: "B3456"},
  {id:3, name: "zen", cid: "SP", value: "B3456"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", cid: "FI", value: "C5678"},
]

const listarr2 =[
  {id:1, name: "dino", cid: "IN", value: "A1234"},
  {id:2, name: "hem", cid: "IN", value: "B3456"},
  {id:3, name: "zen", cid: "SG", value: "C5678"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", cid: "SP", value: "C5678"},
]

const listarr3 =[
  {id:1, name: "dino", cid: "IN", value: "A1234"},
  {id:2, name: "hem", cid: "IN", value: "B3456"},
  {id:3, name: "zen", cid: "IN", value: "C5678"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", cid: "IN", value: "C5678"},
]



const checkIdMembers = data => {

const ALL = 'ALL'
 const dataObj  = data.reduce((res, d) => {

   const existingValue = res[d.value] || {}
   const existing = existingValue[d.cid] || []
   const existingAll = existingValue[ALL] || []
   
   existingValue[d.cid] = [...existing, d]
   
   if(!listcode.includes(d.cid)){
     existingValue[ALL] = [...existingAll, d]
   }
   res[d.value] = existingValue 
   return res
 }, {})
 return Object.values(dataObj).flatMap(v => {
    return Object.values(v).filter(group => group.length > 1)
 })
 
}

console.log(checkIdMembers(listarr1))
console.log(checkIdMembers(listarr2))
console.log(checkIdMembers(listarr3))
```

I realize that my answer wasn't correct so i edited it.

I was missing one of your prerequisite and I had to change the approach a bit

I transformed your initial array in an object like this

```
{
  "<value>" : {
     "<cid>" : [...elements with same cid and value]
      ....
     "ALL"   : [...elements with same value different cid but not in listcode]
  }
}
```

Once you have this object you can just take the values and than use flatMap on it to merge all groups of array that have length > 1

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks  lot for the solution, can explain a bit and is it possible to do using filter and map?

Comment: thanks for lot for solution, but the flatMap shows error `does not exist on type unknown` when i try `.ts file` shows this error, any alternative for flatMap please

Comment: if you are using typescript you have to define the data type. You have to tell it that you are applying flatMap on an array or use @ts-ignore if you feel lazy

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly what you need but I think you can use a `filter` to get an array of the needed elements.
It looks like this, conditions may vary according to your needs:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "dino",
    cid: "IN",
    value: "A1234"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "hem",
    cid: "IN",
    value: "B3456"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "zen",
    cid: "SG",
    value: "C5678"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "ben",
    cid: "SP",
    value: "C5678"
  },
]

const elementsWithIN = data.filter(el => el.cid === 'IN');
const elementsWithoutINOrSP = data.filter(el => !['IN', 'SP'].includes(el.cid))

console.log('elementsWithIN: ', elementsWithIN)
console.log('elementsWithoutINOrSP: ', elementsWithoutINOrSP)
```

Comment: Check if my post answer your question

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly this is what you want to achieve.

```js
var listcode =["IN","FI"];
var listarr1 =[
  {id:1, name: "dino", cid: "IN", value: "A1234"},
  {id:2, name: "hem", cid: "IN", value: "B3456"},
  {id:3, name: "zen", cid: "SP", value: "B3456"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", cid: "FI", value: "C5678"},
]

var listarr2 =[
  {id:1, name: "dino", cid: "IN", value: "A1234"},
  {id:2, name: "hem", cid: "IN", value: "B3456"},
  {id:3, name: "zen", cid: "SG", value: "C5678"},
  {id:4, name: "ben", cid: "SP", value: "C5678"},
]

//same value , and has "IN" 
//listarr1
const filterForSameIncluding = (codeToInclude, array) =>{
array = array.filter(o => codeToInclude.includes(o.cid));
var countList = array.reduce(function(p, c){
  p[c.value] = (p[c.value] || 0) + 1;
  return p;
}, {});
 return array.filter(function(obj){
  return countList[obj.value] > 1;
});
}

const filterForSameExcluding = (codeToExclude, array) =>{
array = array.filter(o => !codeToExclude.includes(o.cid));
var countList = array.reduce(function(p, c){
  p[c.value] = (p[c.value] || 0) + 1;
  return p;
}, {});
 return array.filter(function(obj){
  return countList[obj.value] > 1;
});
}
//listarr2
//same value no include of `FI or IN` so return

  
  
  const result1 = filterForSameIncluding(["IN"], listarr1);
  const result2 = filterForSameExcluding(["IN", "FI"], listarr2);

  console.log("same value with including codes=",result1)
  console.log("same value with excluding codes=", result2)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but i need one function that applies all conditions,